# Ignore non existing attributes in config file parser python

Tags: python, configparser

I have a function returning 1 list at a time, like below

```
['7:49', 'Section1', '181', '1578', '634', '4055']
['7:49', 'Section2', '181', '1578', '634', '4055']
```

These values are `time,section,count,avg,min,max` (I know this will always be the sequence)
My aim is to alert if any of the values breaches limits defined in a config file.

So I create a config like below

```
[Section1]
Count:10
Min:20
Max:100
Avg:50
[Section2]
Count:10
Min:20
Max:100
Avg:50
```

My function to check max and min limits

```
def checklimit(line):
    print "Inside CheckLimit", line[1],line[4],line[5]
    if line[4] < ConfigSectionMap(line[1])['min'] or line[5] > ConfigSectionMap(line[1])['max']:
        sendAlert(line)
```

This works fine but this could be improved and has some corner cases.
Suppose someone leaves config as below

```
[Section1]
Count:10
Min:
Max:
Avg:50
[Section2]
Count:10
Avg:50
```

Meaning the user only wants to check for Count and Avg. How should these cases be handled in my code so as to check only required parameters given in config file. I have used Config Parser from [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserExamples)

Suggestions for question title improvement are welcome. It was hard to put one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a many ways to approach this. With key lookups, in dictionaries you can use the `dict.get()` method and provide a fallback value.

so instead of

```
ConfigSectionMap(line[1])['min']
```

You can use something like this, which will return `0` if the key does not exist.

```
ConfigSectionMap(line[1]).get('min', 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, I would have ideally liked something which makes the condition always true (there could be case where our default value of  0 is not the sure minimum). eg. if min is not specified in config (meaning user doesnt bother its value) and we set it as 0 but the line[4]  is say -20 , this would lead to false alert !

Comment: @pythonRcpp You can use `float('-inf')` instead of 0 then.

Comment: @Rawing I used the `class AlwaysTrue:
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return True
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return True` as default value, isnt this a better way to do this?

Comment: @pythonRcpp I prefer the `float('-inf')` solution, because it achieves the same results in a clearer way. It's immediately obvious for someone who reads your code that `something > float('-inf')` will be `True`. If they find `something > AlwaysTrue()` instead, they have to look at the `AlwaysTrue` class to understand what's going on. (Yes, the name `AlwaysTrue` kind of gives it away, but most people will _still_ read the class definition just to be sure.)

Comment: so for max I should just do `float('inf')` and for min `float('-inf')` I hope using float is ok ? Most probably the compared value would be an int. Shouldn't matter right ?

Comment: @pythonRcpp That's correct, and yes, there's no problem comparing floats to ints.